# ngModel in select tag - inside ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, select, ngmodel

the ngModel in this example is killing my browser. 
any ideas how to get each table cell ng-model?? (i tried to use (change), and it worked - but changed the selected value)

```
<tr *ngFor="let step of procSteps; let i = index;  let first = first; let last = 
                                      last; let even = even; let odd = odd;">

                <td> <p>{{step.position}}</p> </td>

                <td> <p>{{step.name}}</p> </td>

                <td>
                    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedSystemStep[i]">
                        <option *ngFor="let system of systemModuleList" 
                                [value]="system.id">{{system.name}}</option>
                    </select>
                </td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you please make your question more clear?

Comment: What you want ?

Comment: sorry for not being clear. i have a table that runs by ngFor, and each column is a dropDown (select from external array). i dont know how to handle ngModle in this case. i also tried to use (change) function for each select - in both cases my browser had memory issues without any error in the console. i'm using angular 4.0.0 and ts.

Comment: I updated my answer with a demo, hopefully it can help you :)

Comment: Hey how did it go with the updated answer? Did it help? :)

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT:**

Depending on your requirements, you could also add a new property to objects in your existing array, which stores the value from the dropdown to each object, something like:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let step of procSteps; let i = index">
  <td> <p>{{step.position}}</p> </td>
  <td>
    <select [(ngModel)]="step.newProp">
      <option *ngFor="let system of systemModuleList" 
        [value]="system.id">{{system.name}}</option>
      </select>
  </td> 
</tr>
```

Demo for both the above and below solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/24rEpkTYKcXvMUMAyU2B?p=preview

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

How about a helper array where you store the id's?

```html
idArr = []
```

In template we use the index of the iteration of `items` and store the `obj.id` to the corresponding indexes:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">  
  <select [(ngModel)]="idArr[i]">  
    <option *ngFor="let obj of objects" [value]="obj.id">{{obj.name}}</option>  
 </select>  
</div>
```

Now you neatly have all the id's stored in the `idArr`.

Comment: Instead of posting your code as an answer, edit your question. You have **so** much code there, I'm not going to try and look for the problem. Help me help you, create a minimal presentation of your issue https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve And if possible, make a plunker that I can work with :)